Python script equivalent to QGIS Generate XYZ tiles (Directory) function
I have been using QGIS Generate XYZ tiles (Directory) tool which outputs my raster to XYZ tiles nicely!
However, I now want to do this outside of the QGIS environment entirely (so no QGIS involvement). I tried looking at the QGIS documentation to see if there were any hints for a python script, but sadly no.
Essentially, how the function works in QGIS is ideal for the basis of a python script:
-Input raster
-Use the extents of the input raster
-Define min and max zoom levels
-Define output directory
I'm just not sure what python libraries I could use to achieve this? I've seen rasterio pop up, but it needs the input raster in 8-bit and 16-bit formats. Mine are float32 so it needs to be compatible with that

Outside the QGIS GUI or without QGIS at all?

@bugmenot123 without qgis at all

what about gdal2tiles.py?

@IanTurton needs the input raster in 8-bit and 16-bit formats

Checkout the RasterioXYZ tool - it likely does exactly what you want which is output XYZ tiles given georeferenced raster data.
